# Not all paths return a value error in Model class

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, ado.net

My model class looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace OEWebPortalMVCVer5.Models
{
 class DenialModel
{
    public Dictionary< string, DataSet> DataSets { get; set; }

    public static DataSet ReadRows(DataSet dataset)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["demo10ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

            string startDate = "1/1/1900";
            string endDate = "12/31/2020";
            conn.Open();
            DataSet dtDS = new DataSet();
            SqlCommand dtCom = new SqlCommand("dbo.cusGenDenialReport", conn);
            dtCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(startDate);
            dtCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(endDate);
            dtCom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataAdapter dtDa = new SqlDataAdapter(dtCom);

            dtDa.Fill(dtDS);
            conn.Close();
            dtCom.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string message = "It didn't work because: " + ex.Message.ToString();
        }
    }
}
}
```

When I attempt to build the solution in VS2012 it throws the following error:

```
Error   1   'OEWebPortalMVCVer5.Models.DenialModel.ReadRows(System.Data.DataSet)': not all code paths return a value    C:\Users\Orchestrate\documents\visual studio 2012\Project\OEWebPortalMVCVer5\OEWebPortalMVCVer5\Models\DenialModel.cs   22  31  OEWebPortalMVCVer5
```

My first thought was that I did not handle the null value for the parameter startDate and endDate so I hard coded them and will address that later.  That was not the case so I added a try catch block to get the error.  Well that of course didn't help (I must have gotten very tired to think that the try catch would magically fix it).  I have googled this error and searched this site and haven't found any related answers to this problem.

I am not sure how to get the code to compile properly at this point.  Any help is appreciated

Thank you

Comment: The error says exactly what's the problem : there's no `return` statement in your function.

Comment: @Johnny5 That's the answer, you should post it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says exactly what's the problem : there's no `return` statement in your function.

```
public static DataSet ReadRows(DataSet dataset)
    {
        DataSet dtDS = null;
        try
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["demo10ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

            string startDate = "1/1/1900";
            string endDate = "12/31/2020";
            conn.Open();
            dtDS = new DataSet();
            SqlCommand dtCom = new SqlCommand("dbo.cusGenDenialReport", conn);
            dtCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(startDate);
            dtCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(endDate);
            dtCom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataAdapter dtDa = new SqlDataAdapter(dtCom);

            dtDa.Fill(dtDS);
            conn.Close();
            dtCom.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //You probably should let it break...
            string message = "It didn't work because: " + ex.Message.ToString();
        }

        return dtDS;
    }
```

Comment: Is this true even when using a view?  Please excuse my question if it is stupid but I am just learning

Comment: The error is not in any case related to MVC or whatever. In C#, a function _have_ to return a value, unless its return type is set to _void_, in witch case it _never_ returns a value.

Comment: In addition, you cannot return different types in different case, like you can do in non-strongly-typed languages like javascript or (I think) php.